# Filenet - Voting approval routing

Tags: filenet-process-engine, filenet-cpe

I have a step in my workflow where only a certain number of approvals are required, rather requiring that all participants approve the step & I stumbled on this page (see the very last step 9d) - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.xt.user.doc/ae_help/entry/et_define_wf_step6prop_stepinfo.htm
I don't see that step in my workflow. Can anybody please help me to navigate that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only showing when you create / modify for the following two type of workflow definitions which are compatible with Entry template. 
[Fixed Approval Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBOr0.png)
Here it is [The checkbox you were looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC3xW.png)

Comment: You need to create a data field to handle the counting within the workflow definition if you want to implement this voting approval in a custom designed workflow.